# Stack overflow when defining Haskell Fibonacci

Tags: haskell, stack-overflow, fibonacci

Just trying to do Exercise 3.7 (p. 31) of Hal Daumé III's YAHT manual, I tried to define the Fibonacci function:

```
fibo 1 = 1
fibo 2 = 1
fibo n = fibo(n-1) + fibo(n-2)
```

I then requested

```
fibo(3)
```

and got:

```
*** Exception: stack overflow
```

When I looked into the solution of the exercise I found exactly the same code (with the difference that the function is called fib instead of fibo). What am I doing wrong?

(The manual is from 2006, maybe the language has changed inbetween?)
(It is ironic that I ask stackoverflow for a problem of stack overflow…)

Comment: Multiline statements in `ghci` need to be wrapped between `:{` and `:}` or you should use another mechanism. Right now you defined a new function `fibo` in the second line, and another one in the third line.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is likely the result of defining the function in `ghci` one line at a time. This means that you first define a function `fibo 1 = 1`. Then you define *another* function with the name `fibo` (with `fibo 2 = 2`) that is scoped more locally, and finally you define a third function named `fibo`.

You can wrap multi-line functions between `:{` and `:}`, and thus define *one* function `fibo` that consists out of three clauses:

```
Prelude> :{
Prelude| fibo 1 = 1
Prelude| fibo 2 = 1
Prelude| fibo n = fibo (n-1) + fibo (n-2)
Prelude| :}
Prelude> fibo 3
2
```

Comment: Thanks! Incidentally I have a question: in a program in which a number is asked from the user and the program replies with "Too high!" or "Too low!" until the user guesses the right number, there is a Haskell code line `guess <- getLine` and then `guess` is used. Isn't that like using a variable in an imperative language? What distinguishes this `guess` from a `$guess` in Perl that gets a new value whenever the user types a new number?

Comment: @yannis: no. In fact `do` notation is just syntactic sugar. If you write `x <- foo; bar x`, it will be rewritten to `foo >>= \x -> bar x`. Furthermore just like all data in Haksell, the variables are *immutable*. So once set, you can never set the variable to a different value. So `do` is nothing "special". It is in fact just syntax to make it more convenient to write long chains with the "bind" function `>>=`. Furthermore you can use `do` for all sorts of monads like `IO`, `Maybe`, `Q`, `[]`, etc.

Comment: @yannis A `do` block might indeed look like imperative programming, but it's not the same thing. Still, in a recursive IO-based block where we have `guess <- getLine`, you can expect `guess` to get the new value from the user each time, very much like imperative programming. Note that we do not have mutable variables here, each recursive call creates its own "local" `guess` variable and binds it to a value. To really understand IO, I'd recommend to read some IO tutorial.

Comment: @Willem that is not helpful to a newbie. :) yes, the `x` in `foo = do { x <- getLine ; printResponse x ; foo }` is just like an imperative variable being overwritten over and over *in a loop* (to which any self-respecting implementation ought to compile that code, I hope so very much), the implementational details notwithstanding. there's an "IO without monads" tutorial somewhere, IIRC.

Comment: @chi I hope very much that it *is* compiled into a proper loop with the constant stack usage, in effect overwriting the variable's binding in that stack frame that is being reused (just like a TCO loop in Scheme would). I include a code snippet in my comment above. does GHC not do that? after all that's the only mechanism available to us to express IO loops, is it not?

Comment: @WillNess: well it gives a wrong impression that for example `x <- getLine; do {x <- getLine }; print x` would print the value that is set by the inner `getLine`. But it is not, since that is a locally scoped one. So the reassignment of a variable is different than that in Perl. Unfortunately a lot of questions on Haskell are from people that do not understand that.

Comment: I referred specifically to the example as in my comment. (also your `do` code isn't valid, so your intent isn't clear :) ).

Comment: @WillNess: but the question is, is `x` a variable like in Perl. The answer is clearly no. Since in Perl a variable can be overrwritten. The fact that internally Haskell compiles to an imperative program is not very relevant. imho. Furthermore I think most Haskell implementations have not a *call* stack. They only have a pattern stack, so there is, to the best of my knowledge, often not a stack frame (or at least not one like in an imperative language).

Comment: I'd expect it to be compiled down to some C--. and for a novice user what it *does* is what counts (so the answer is, *in a loop, it is*), but that's of course an issue of teaching / presentation (and performance, too! ), not of the essence of the language. :) YMWV.

Comment: @WillNess: well it basically has an evaluation engine if I recall correctly, and that one uses an evaluation stack. Then egine might use calls, but thee will not increase/decrease with the languages one so to speak. But nevertheless, at a language level, I think it is not a good idea to claim that a Haskell variable and a Perl variable are the same. Since a Perl variable can change its value throughout the program. Whereas a Haskell one can not. Two variables in Haskell can have the same name (like variable scoping allows that in many languages), but then the two are not the same conceptually.

Comment: probably you didn't get my point, but never mind that.  a TCO loop in Scheme  without `set!`  as an example runs in constant stack space, reuses call frame, in effect overwrites a variable's binding, is what I'm saying. I don't see how this is invalid. scoping and naming is totally orthogonal to this.

Comment: @WillNess Yes, since recursion is the only way to loop in Haskell, a kind of TCO is needed to allow constant space loops. Still, the GHC runtime is pretty complex, and evolved from push/enter STG to eval/apply STG (IIRC), so it's not entirely trivial to speak about TCO there.

Comment: Using the `IO` monad is essentially imperative programming.  Haskell has a particular take on it which is interesting to understand, but basically `IO` is the "imperative" monad and if that's what it feels like, it's no surprise. Still what has been said here about variable scopes is important.